# Why does awk always print full lines?

Tags: bash, macos, awk

When attempting to use `awk` to get the process ID from the output of `ps aux` like so:

```
ps aux | awk "{ print $2 }"
```

No matter what number of row I attempt to print, `awk` always outputs the full line. I've never managed to get it to work properly. I'm using macOS which apparently uses a different type/version of `awk`, but I can't find an alternative syntax which might work.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Replace `"`s with `'`s.

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Answer (score 1):

```
ps aux | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

Try that one

Comment: You might need to add a "-" in front of the ps command line options: ps -aux | ...